# Padding Issue of Long Hashes

Tags: c++, hash, cryptography

For crypto experts, I have a question that recently came into my mind. So, for example, think that we have a long string of bytes and we want to put that string into a hash function which we may take for the sake of illustration as SHA1. As we know, SHA1 takes inputs in 64 bytes chunks and every hash function afaik needs to pad the message before processing. Now the question is that is it the last chunk that needs to be padded or the whole string? It will matter because at the end of padding we will append the length. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now the question is that is it the last chunk that needs to be padded or the whole string?

I believe both the things are same. Padding the whole string means padding the last chunk only.

Some pseudocode from good old wiki [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1#SHA-1_pseudocode)

A Look at the code might give you some insights :

Taken from : [mattmahoney.net/dc/sha1.c](http://mattmahoney.net/dc/sha1.c)

```
void SHA1PadMessage(SHA1Context *context)
{
    /*
     *  Check to see if the current message block is too small to hold
     *  the initial padding bits and length.  If so, we will pad the
     *  block, process it, and then continue padding into a second
     *  block.
     */
    if (context->Message_Block_Index > 55)
    {
        context->Message_Block[context->Message_Block_Index++] = 0x80;
        while(context->Message_Block_Index < 64)
        {
            context->Message_Block[context->Message_Block_Index++] = 0;
        }

        SHA1ProcessMessageBlock(context);

        while(context->Message_Block_Index < 56)
        {
            context->Message_Block[context->Message_Block_Index++] = 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        context->Message_Block[context->Message_Block_Index++] = 0x80;
        while(context->Message_Block_Index < 56)
        {

            context->Message_Block[context->Message_Block_Index++] = 0;
        }
    }

    /*
     *  Store the message length as the last 8 octets
     */
    context->Message_Block[56] = context->Length_High >> 24;
    context->Message_Block[57] = context->Length_High >> 16;
    context->Message_Block[58] = context->Length_High >> 8;
    context->Message_Block[59] = context->Length_High;
    context->Message_Block[60] = context->Length_Low >> 24;
    context->Message_Block[61] = context->Length_Low >> 16;
    context->Message_Block[62] = context->Length_Low >> 8;
    context->Message_Block[63] = context->Length_Low;

    SHA1ProcessMessageBlock(context);
}
```

Comment: But in your case length of the whole string is not equal to the length of the last non-padded portion of the string. And after padding we need to insert the length in the last 8 bytes. But which length is this? Is it the length of the whole message?

Comment: If so thanks, very subtle details sometimes blurs things :)

Comment: @EsadA.Tokat I have provided a link in my answer. You can google for open source implementations of SHA-1. I myself have done it before.

Comment: @EsadA.Tokat please accept and upvote the answer if you found it useful

Comment: It is the same thing that can be found here https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3174 and I have adapted that portion into my needs. Thanks anyway and upvoted as well :)